# Let Swing JSplitPane support one-touch-resize, but not drag

Tags: java, swing

I'm using a Horizontally oriented JSplitPane in my application.

I have a control panel on the left-hand side and an editor on the right. It does not make sense to resize the control panel; its layout is too sensitive. So, I'd like either it to be displayed or not.

The JSplitPane component almost meets my requirement (particularly the one-touch-resize behaviour shown below). But I do not wish to allow the user to drag the resize bar: I just want the one-touch behaviour.

```
splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
```

Any pointers to how to do this?

Comment: `I just want the one-touch behaviour.` - how, where, why, is mouse click, from TouchScreen, ... for better help sooner, please post http://sscce.org/

Comment: Hi @mKorbel I understand the role of sscce, but this question isn't specific to my instance. I don't have broken code, I wish to learn about a mode of usage of the Swing JSplitPane component.  I don't believe this Java Swing question has a TouchScreen context.

Comment: ianmayo I never seen differencies betweens mouse and finger click on the screen in Java6, your question missed JComponents and used LayoutManager

Comment: @mKorbel with "one-touch" expandable he just means the functionality of the split pane where you can use little arrows to move the divider all the way to one side or the other. It has nothing to do with touch screens. It's an unfortunate name though, it should rather be called "one-click" expandable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do this with `JSplitPane`.

Use `JideSplitSpane` from [Jide Common Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) (GPL with classpath exception) instead. Then do:

```
JideSplitPane splitPane = ...;
splitPane.setDragResizable(false);
splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
```

`JideSplitSpane` has several other advantages compared to `JSplitPane`such as allowing multiple splits.

Answer (score 0):

```
splitPane.setEnabled( false );
```

Comment: Invalid, since this would also disable the one-touch-resize behaviour.

Comment: @ianmayo, Did you actually test this or just assume it won't work? It works fine when using the Metal LAF which is how I tested it. Maybe you have a LAF issue, which doesn't make my answer wrong. Post the test code that you used.

Comment: yes, I tested that before posting. Beyond that, it would be illogical for setEnabled(false) to leave part of the component enabled.  See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled(boolean)

Comment: @ianmayo, so post your code demonstrating the problem. It works fine for me with every LAF I've tested. Its illogical to ank a question and then not follow up with code when you've been given a one line solution! Nothing in your question states what LAF or platform you are using. So I can only assume you have a problem with your code until you can post a SSCCE that proves otherwise!

Comment: don't understand why these comments, SSCCE is unarguable form how to ask question without flame_wars +1

Comment: +1 I had the same problem. But I figured out that I need to call `setEnabled(false)` before `setOneTouchExpandable(true)` not after it.